# Debugging problem with the RSL10 microcontroller

Tags: debugging, jtag

I am using the *onSemiconductor* 3.5.285 version which is compatible with the NCH-RSL10-101WC51-ABG (I can debug and drive my pins correctly). However, I can't drive my pins on the NCV-RSL10-101Q48-AVG. Moreover, when I want to debug the NCV-RSL10-101Q48-AVG. I get stuck on the following comments:

```
Reading common registers: Read register 'r0' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x02000000
Read register 'r1' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x00000000
Read register 'r2' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x000000C0
Read register 'r3' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x00000020
Read register 'r4' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x00000000
Read register 'r5' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0xFFFFFFFF
Read register 'r6' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0xFFFFFFFF
Read register 'r7' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x2C0E0040
Read register 'r8' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x00A70042
Read register 'r9' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x001A0800
Read register 'r10' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x27F7DCB9
Read register 'r11' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0xD1EF8DDD
Read register 'r12' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x01000000
Read register 'sp' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0xE01F0020
Read register 'lr' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0xCF020000
Read register 'pc' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x56010000
Read register 'xpsr' (4 bytes) from hardware: 0x00000081

Setting breakpoint @ address `0x0012BD00, Kind = 2, Type = THUMB, BPHandle = 0x0001`
Starting target CPU...
```

I would like to know if this pack version is also compatible with the NCV-RSL10-101Q48-AVG?
If not, which one shall I use ?